# Include an outer folder in git repository referencing it

Tags: git

I have a source folder with the following structure (child folders) :

- MAIN_FOLDER

  - PROGRAM1
  - PROGRAM2
  - COMMONMODULE
  - PROGRAM3
  - PROGRAM4

Each of the program use some delphi unit files included into the `COMMONMODULE`, now I have to create a git repository for each of the program and I need a way to reference the `COMMONMODULE`, folder without duplicating its content in each program repository, is it possible ?

What is the best way ?

Answer (score 1):

[Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) is what you are looking for.